# removing reference to printf built-in function

Tags: c, gcc

I faced a stack overflow problem in my STM32F4xx project. It came out that printf is the cause. FreeRTOS support suggests to use printf-stdarg.c instead.
I have removed all stdio.h includes in my project. It complains of "incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf'" but compiles OK meaning the linker has used the built-in library.

My question is how to how to prevent linker (gcc) from using built-in printf/sprintf function.

Comment: How does that error mean it used the built-in library?

Comment: I am using SW4STM32 under eclipse.

Comment: it only uses the standard one cos you're not supplying an alternative

Comment: You can include any header you want that defines `int printf(const char *format, ...)`.

Comment: @Scott Hunter: it is not error. it is a warning only.

Comment: Using the stream-IO functions on bare-metal embedded platforms is most times a bad idea. They just bloat the code, attract a lot of secondary functions and are slow. Use specialised functions to serialise data instead. And gcc is not a linker and that is not a linker warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you linked printf-stdarg.c into your executable, then that function will be called instead of the system defined `printf`.  The functions in standard library are **weak symbols**, which means you can define a function of the same name which will override the system function.

Removing `#include <stdio.h>` doesn't prevent the system library from being linked in.  It just gets rid of the function prototypes your code needs.

Put the includes back in your code and link with printf-stdarg.c, and your code will use those functions.

Comment: Thanks. I will test it. Bear with me.